# Set Select option not working Jquery inside html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was used jquery function inside HTML form. I tried to select an option using the parseJSON method but not working. This is working on modal view.

code for modal view popup

```
function EditAppoinment(id){

$.post('php/owner_appoinment_edit_get_values.php',{id:id},function (data) {
    var formedit = EditForm(data);
    $('.modal-body').html(formedit);
    $('#orumodal').modal('show');
});
}
```

jquery code for form

```
function EditForm(values)
{
    var obj = $.parseJSON(values);

    $('#appstatus').val(obj.status);

    var html = '<form method="post" action="">';
            html += '<div class="form-group">' +
                        '<label>Appinment date</label>' +
                        '<input type="text" name="app_date" class="form-control" value="'+ obj.app_date +'" placeholder="Appoinment Date">' +
                    '</div>';
            html += '<div class="form-group">' +
                        '<label>Appinment Time</label>' +
                        '<input type="text" name="app_time" class="form-control" value="'+ obj.app_time +'" placeholder="Appoinment Time">' +
                    '</div>';
            html += '<div class="form-group">' +
                        '<label>Description</label>' +
                        '<textarea rows="3" name="desc" class="form-control" placeholder="Description">'+ obj.description +'</textarea>' +
                    '</div>';
            html += '<div class="form-group"><label>Status</label>' +
                        '<select name="appstatus" id="appstatus" class="form-control">' +
                            '<option value="success">Success</option>' +
                            '<option value="failed">Failed</option>' +
                            '<option value="processing">Processing</option>' +
                        '</select>' +
                    '</div>';
            html += '<div class="form-group">' +
                        '<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Update</button>'
                    '</div>';
           return html += '</form>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are overwriting the content using `.html()`, set value after it

```
$.post('php/owner_appoinment_edit_get_values.php', {
    id: id
}, function (data) {
    //Parse JSON
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    var formedit = EditForm(obj );      
    $('.modal-body').html(formedit);

    //Set value after setting HTML
    $('#appstatus').val(obj.status);

    $('#orumodal').modal('show');
});
```

Additionally, You should parse JSON in success callback and pass it to `EditForm()` method

```
function EditForm(obj) {
    var html = '<form method="post" action="">';
    ....
}
```